# How to update edited row in DataTables

Tags: json, ajax, datatables

I am trying to edit row in a Datatable.Data is loading from the database.after clicking on row popup will come. then editing the field after clicking on submit button it's not updating.
In console network error is 403.
Forbidden. How to update edited row ?

```
var workorder_path = "/dashboard/workorder_list/0/?format=json";

var editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
    ajax: {


edit: {
                        type: 'PUT',
                        dataType:"json",
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        url: '/dashboard/workorder_list/0/?format=json',
                        data: function ( d ) {
                            return JSON.stringify( d );
                        }
                    },


  },
    table: "#workorder_table",
    idSrc: "id",
    fields: [
        { label: "ID:", name: "id" },
        { label: "Task:",   name: "task.name" },
        { label: "Description:",   name: "description" },

        { label: "Start Date:",   name: "start_date",
                "type": "datetime" },
        { label: "End Date:",   name: "end_date",
                "type": "datetime" }
    ]
} );





var workorder_table = $('#workorder_table').dataTable({
    dom: 'Blfrtip',
    JQueryUI: true,
    bPaginate: false,
    sScrollX: "100%",
    responsive: true,
    select: true,
    buttons: [
        {
            text: 'New',
            action: function () {
                create_workorder_window();
            },
            className: 'btn btn-warning btn-outline'
        },
        { extend: "edit",   editor: editor, className: 'btn btn-warning btn-outline' },
       // { extend: "create", editor: editor },
        { extend: 'colvis', text: 'Show', className: 'btn btn-warning btn-outline'}
    ],
    ajax: {
        url: workorder_path,
        dataSrc: ''
    },
    columns: [
        {"data": "id", "class": "workorder_id"},
        {"data": "thumb", "render": function(data, type, row) {
                                        return `<a href=` + data + ` data-fancybox> <img src=` + data + ` width="80" height="45"> </a>`;
                                    }},
        {"data": "task.name"},
        {"data": "description"},
        {"data": "status", "class":"v-a-m", "render": function (status, type, row) {
                                                return `<div class="media media-auto">
                                                            <div class="media-left">
                                                                <div class="avatar">
                                                                    <img class="media-object img-circle"
                                                                         src=${ status.image }
                                                                         alt=${ status.name }
                                                                         title=${ status.name }>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                           <div class="media-body">
                                                                <span class="media-heading">${ status.name }</span>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>`;

        } },
        {"data": "start_date", "visible": false},
        {"data": "end_date", "visible": false},
        {"data": "assign_to", "width": "400px", "defaultContent": "None", "render": function (assign_to, type, row) {

                                                return `<div class="media media-auto">
                                                        <div class="media-left">
                                                            <div class="avatar">
                                                                <img class="media-object img-circle"
                                                                     src=${ assign_to.photo }
                                                                     alt=${ assign_to.official_name }>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="media-body">
                                                            <span class="media-heading text-white">${ assign_to.official_name }</span>
                                                            <br>
                                                            <span class="text-gray-lighter"><span>${ assign_to.designation.designation }</span></span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>`

        } },
        {"data": "creation_time", "visible": false},
        {"data": "modified_time", "visible": false}
    ]
});
```

Comment: You are calling the same URL, workorder_path = "/dashboard/workorder_list/0/?format=json", to load Databale as well as edit a row.

Comment: var workorder_path = "/dashboard/workorder_list/0/?format=json";
to pass the data to server i have to give another url?

Comment: This is wrong. You are calling the same function in both. I mean to load the datatable and to update a row. See, to load a datatable, u should call a get method. For update, you need to call a Put or Post method, wher u can pass data. Right. Otherwise how u will pass your updated data to server. Can u please add your server side edit method in your question. Yes u need to give another url.

Comment: i added put method in ajax edit.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling same function for both (to load data in data table as well as to update a record), I mean the URL that you have mentioned in your question.

So, inside your edit ajax function, you need to call another server side method, where you can pass your data. For example,

```
[HttpPut]
public returnType EditRecord(int id, WorkorderModel model)
 {
   //Here you can update the record then return a success message or whatever
   return message;
 }
```

**Note:**  See, I don't know in which Language you are writing. As I'm writing in C#, so I added `HttpPut attribute` on top of the `EditRecord method`, to make it `PUT`. You need to change it accordingly.

Then, from your client side edit ajax, you can call it like this,

```
url: '/dashboard/EditRecord/'+d.id,
```

Just change the URL, that you have written in your ajax edit. See, here **d.id** is nothing but your **record id**, that you are going to update.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I am rendering table using datatables javascript. i am not using django models. its directly rendering from the javascript.